# How to loop through XML node and its child node to get the SQL and Mail Address

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read an xml with the following format given below in C# . I have to store each sql Text and mailbody content and each email address under customer tag into a string variable for further process. The XML format I have given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Queries>
    <Customer>
        <SQL ID="GYSQL">
            Select * from customer where code ='GYSQL'
        </SQL>
        <MailBody>
              Please find  the Report GY
        </MailBody>
        <Address>customer1@mail.com</Address>
        <Address>customer2@mail.com</Address>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <SQL ID="TSSQL">
            Select * from customer where code ='TSSQL'
        </SQL>
        <MailBody>
              Please find  the Report TS
        </MailBody>
        <Address>customer3@mail.com</Address>
        <Address>customer4@mail.com</Address>
        <Address>customer5@mail.com</Address>
    </Customer>
</Queries>
```

I have to loop through Each Customer Tag

```
  var xml = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\xml\\sql.xml";
                XmlDocument xml1 = new XmlDocument();
                xml1.Load(xml);
                XmlNodeList list = xml1.SelectNodes(@"//Customer");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in list)
                {
                    
                    string Sql = Get the text from SQL tag under Customer
                    string mailbody = Get the text under tag Customer\Mailbody
                    //Here I have to get each email address in a loop in a string variable

                }
```

Comment: try xn.value ....

Comment: @PeterMarshall That's the value of the Customer node, not what the poster wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep going with XPath expressions, you could do something like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in list)
{   
    // Find the first child node of 'xn' with name "SQL"
    var sqlForThisCustomer = xn.SelectSingleNode("SQL")?.InnerText;
    // Same for "MailBody"
    var mailBodyForThisCustomer = xn.SelectSingleNode("MailBody")?.InnerText;   

    var addressList = xn.SelectNodes("Address");
    foreach(XmlNode adr in addressList) {
        var currentAddress = adr.InnerText;     
    }
}
```

For this sort of work I usually prefer `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);
var customers = doc.Root
            .Elements("Customer")
            .Select(c => new {
                SQL = c.Element("SQL")?.Value,
                MailBody = c.Element("MailBody")?.Value,
                Addresses = c.Elements("Address").Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: How can I get Each email address under the tag <Address>

Comment: Added that to the example now, I somehow missed your comment in the question.